# Access words by index in python

Tags: python, cs50

I don't know if it's possible but i'm trying to access words (not individual characters) from a split string by indexes and store it in a dictionary. If this can't work, pls is there any other suggestion as to how to go about getting the same result. This is my code so far:

```
def main():
if len(argv) != 2:
    print("usage: python import.py (csv file)")
    exit(0)


db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

file = open(argv[2], 'r')
csv_file = DictReader(file)

for row in csv_file:
    names = row['name']
    for i in names:
        word = i.split()

  # what the csv looks like
  name,house,birth
  Adelaide Murton,Slytherin,1982
  Adrian Pucey,Slytherin,1977
  Anthony Goldstein,Ravenclaw,1980
   
  # what i want it to look like
  first name,middle name,last name,house,birth
  Adelaide,None,Murton,Slytherin,1982
  Adrian,None,Pucey,Slytherin,1977
  Anthony,None,Goldstein,Ravenclaw,1980
```

Comment: It would help if you provided some context such as the structure of your CSV and a sample of what your final data structure would look like. Are you looking to have the dictionary keep by words and values representing a list of CSV rows that contain the particular key? If this is the case, you could enumerate the data, and use setdefault to add the word as a key if it does not yet exist and append the current index from the generator. We can help you out with a bit more context. :)

Comment: i've updated the code to show the structure of the csv file and what i want it to look like afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If there is a comma between the words then you can do `words = i.split(',')` or whatever the delimiter is passed in as an argument to `split()`

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = 'This is an example'  # string: 'This is an example'
words = sentence.split()         # list of strings: ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']
```

At this point you can get a specific word by calling its index, or loop through them like `for word in words:`.

I'm not sure about the SQL portion of your code but it looks like you're already looping through the words when you do `for i in names:`.

Comment: does that mean this syntax is correct:
   ` ...names = row['name'].split()
        if len(names) == 2:
            name_column = {'first name' = name[0]}...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
def create_word_index(filenames, rare_word_flag=False):
    word_index, word_count, single_words = {}, 0, []  # original : word_count = 0

    ## Handle word index and word count
    for idx, filename in enumerate(filenames):
        with open(filename) as f:
            for sentence in f.readlines():
                words = sentence.strip().split()
                for word in words:
                    # word = process(word)  # Do more preprocessing stuff here if you need
                    if rare_word_flag and (word in single_words):
                        word_index[word] = 1
                        continue
                    if word in word_index:
                        continue
                    word_index[word] = word_count
                    word_count += 1
    return word_index, word_count


filenames = ["haha.txt"]
word_idx, word_count = create_word_index(filenames, False)
print(word_idx)
print(word_count)

# haha.txt file:
name=huhu, check=ok
name=haha, check=not good
```